# Minimal Windowless OpenGL Context Initialization

Tags: c++, opengl, wgl

How can I initialize a windowless OpenGL context with the minimal amount of code?

I've read [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context) that you can use `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` to create windowless context, however it doesn't explain how?

Comment: Why do you need it ? To render into an image, or use compute shader for GPGPU ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the link:

> Creating a context without a window, for off-screen rendering. This may not actually work.

That second sentence is important. From the [WGL_ARB_create_context specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/WGL_ARB_create_context.txt):

> 4) Should there be a way to make a context current without binding
>       it to a window system drawable at the same time?
>
> RESOLVED: Yes, but only in OpenGL 3.0 and later. This results in a
>       context with an invalid default framebuffer, the meaning of which is
>       defined in the OpenGL 3.0 specification.
>
> NOTE: Apparently on Windows, opengl32.dll makes use of the drawable
>       argument to identify the namespace of the driver, so we may not be
>       able to work around it.

The specification doesn't allow you to *create* a context without a window, since it needs the pixel format that you set into the device context. But you *theoretically* can pass NULL for the HDC when making the context current, which causes OpenGL to not have a default framebuffer.

But, as noted above, this may not actually work. You can try it to see what happens, but I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then what is the most minimalistic way to create a windowless context?

Comment: Another try would be the use the screen DC (passing NULL to *GetDC* routine).

Comment: @Luca: You must not set the PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR of the root/screen window! And the drawable a OpenGL context is bound to must have a compatible pixelformat. Hence your suggestion is very bad advice.

Answer (score 6):

The usual way to implement offscreen rendering is:

1. Create a dummy window + OpenGL context to get access to extensions
2. Obtain the functions to create a PBuffer
3. Create a PBuffer DC
4. Create an OpenGL context on the PBuffer
5. Destroy the dummy window

Another option is using Framebuffer Objects (FBO) by which you create a regular OpenGL window, but instead of rendering to the main framebuffer you render to Framebuffer Object buffers, with the OpenGL window being made invisible.

Comment: For a beginner would that be possible to have a code snippet?

Answer (score -3):

another stuff:

```
HDC  hdc = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY",NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

But  `ReleaseDC` not work with it.DeleteDC does.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? `ReleaseDC` and `DeleteDC` are not equivalents for each other, they serve completely different purposes.