# example code and API to log a user on and create a session and desktop - looking for - for Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, authentication, windows-services

I am looking for example code and API to log a user on and create a session and desktop for Windows 7.

I need do this from a non-interactive process running as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to archive, but if you just want a new session and its desktop, check the LogonUser function sample. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379608(VS.85).aspx.

If you are trying to do graphics, check [Windows 2008 RenderFarm Service: CreateProcessAsUser "Session 0 Isolation" and OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464182/windows-2008-renderfarm-service-createprocessasuser-session-0-isolation-and-op)