# OpenGl in Windows 7 Service

Tags: opengl, windows-7, windows-services, ipc, session-0-isolation

Is there any way to use hardware accelerated OpenGl from a Windows 7 Service?
The normal Session 0 has no access to the graphics card driver.

Is there any way to configure the service that this is possible (e.g. specify user)?

I´m aware that there are possibilities for starting a new process, but using IPC would render the whole purpose of using hardware acceleration useless.

i also checked [this SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464182/windows-2008-renderfarm-service-createprocessasuser-session-0-isolation-and-o), but it also creates a new process.

Comment: "*using IPC would render the whole purpose of using hardware acceleration useless.*" That rather depends on your IPC mechanism and the way you structure your IPC messaging and handling code. There's no reason you can't get reasonable performance with IPC; Chrome is practically built on the stuff.

Comment: You´re right. It depends. But for our scenario it really is evil, as we use the service to render images interactive over http. So latency is king. We have a managed C# http server using a native opengl application and so we would have to pass every frame over IPC to the HTTP Server and from there over HTTP.